# Pylab plot with x axis not evenly sliced

Tags: matplotlib

I am pretty new using pylab/matplotlib, and I try to plot a simple graph as I would do in excel but I have an issue with the x axis. I have a 2d vector X and I do:

```
 pylab.plot(X[:,0],Y[:,1])
```

The values of `X[:,0]` are reals and ranked. When the plot appears, the value of `X` have been sliced and put in intervals of same size. So for example, I have a few points between -10 and -5, and many points between -5 and 0, but on the x-axis those intervals have the same size. How can I plot just the raw data for the x-axis?
Thank for your help

Edit: sorry i know it is not very clear. For example.if i have 100 points with x belonging to [0,5] and 3 points with x belonging to [5,10], plot(x,y) gives a plot where the distance between 0and 5 is the same as between 5 and 10. I want this distance to depends.on the number of points in the interval ( like when you plot a "line graph" in excel)
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the definition of `X` and `Y` to your example code.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "the raw data for the x-axis". `plot(x, y)` will draw one line with points at `(x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1]), ... (x[-1], y[-1])` (in python `X[-1]` means the last value in `X`). If you just want to plot the values in `X`, you should do `plot(X)`. This will draw a line with points at `(0, X[0]), (1, X[1]), ... (len(X)-1, X[-1])`.